# AS3 - Chroma Keying in pure AS

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, matrix, chromakey, colormatrixfilter

Let's say I have a bitmap with 3 circles (red , purple , yellow), I would like (in pure AS, no PixelBender) to post process the image and set the alpha of the yellow pixels to 0.

Can I use the `ColorMatrixFilter` class, or should I iterate over the entire `bitmapData`?

[**`This`**](http://www.quasimondo.com/archives/000615.php) example uses AS2, I'm looking for something similar in AS3

Comment: +1 for the link, spectacular!

Comment: It should not be too difficult to port that example's code to AS3, or at least read it and see what it's doing. Especially the `ColorMatrix` class is almost AS3 already, apart from some minor syntax changes.

Comment: I'm gonna do it... Looking for a quick solution

Answer (score 0):

I think this [ColorMatrixFilter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/ColorMatrixFilter.html) would do what you are asking

```
matrix.concat([1, 1, 0, 0, 0]);
```